# Why isn't my single post template showing up correctly?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to figure out how to create a custom single post template on wordpress. I'm not very familiar with it but was required to use it.

I've followed the steps required to create it but it seems that my new post template called educators is still referencing the original post template instead of the one i've created for it.

Here is my single-post_educator.php file code.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <img src="<?php the_field('post_banner','option');?>" style="width :100%;">
    <div class="container">
        <?php if (have_posts()) :
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php if( get_field('post_content_right') ) { ?>
            <div class="post-right col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <h2><?php echo get_the_title();?></h2>
                <p><?php echo the_field('post_content');?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 post-right">
            <a href="<?php echo home_url();?>/#educator" style="font-size: 
            15px;color:#000000;float:right;font-family: 'calibri';text-
            decoration: underline;text-align:right;">Back</a>

                <p><?php echo the_field('post_content_right');?></p>
        </div>
        <?php } else { ; ?>
        <div class="post-right col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <a href="<?php echo home_url();?>/#educator" style="font-size: 
            15px;color:#000000;float:right;font-family: 'calibri';text-
            decoration:underline;text-align:right;">Back</a>

            <h2><?php echo get_the_title();?></h2>
            <p><?php echo the_field('post_content');?></p>
        </div>
        <?php } ;?>
        <?php
        endwhile;
        endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I included a photo of how it currently is and how i actually want it to be like:

[image: my question]

Thanks in advance.. help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file should be named:

```
single-{post_type}.php
```

So in your case it should be

```
single-post_educators.php
```

You're missing the `s`

Comment: Hi Giolliao, is that the file name you are talking about? As for mine i called it single-post_educators

Comment: Oh i just realised i missed on the E will change it and try again thanks!

Comment: Hi Giolliao, after adding on the S, the template refers correctly but now the content isn't displaying may i understand what is the cause of this?

Comment: Maybe ask a new question or we can go into chat for this. Your initial answer solved? you should mark this as complete

Comment: yes the template is somewhat referencing correctly right now thanks alot. how do i go about into a chat with you?

Comment: hi giolliao, i need to wait 90minutes before i can post again.. is there some error in the settings i have done? or some possible scenarios which causes the content in the post not to show?

Comment: Maybe just copy single.php contents into your new template and see if that works? if not you might have to look at your apache error logs

Comment: hmm still not working on that part. where can i go to take a look at the error log file?

Comment: i figured out the issue thanks so much! its got to do with my custom field settings.